# Looking for SQL DB with all US zip codes, states, and cities that is up-to-date

Tags: mysql, sql

Does anyone know where I can find a pregenerated database that has all zip codes and their corresponding city and state?

EDIT: Or is there any webservice that provides this functionality?

Comment: And it is supposed to cover entire Earth? And this isn't programming question, it's a request...

Comment: im asking for advice on where I might find one, not asking someone to cough up one they have or something.

Comment: search `bing` or `google` plenty of vendors out there, might want to try USPS too

Comment: @sightofnick, OK, im just stating because 'I need...' :)

Comment: i think it's a great question!

Comment: Check out https://www.geonames.org/postal-codes/ . They let you download their data under a [CC BY 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) but from my experience with their Canadian postal codes the data isn't perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about <s>[this](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools-address-information.htm?)</s>?Not precisely what you asked for, but if your app has internet connectivity, it's probably what you want; never wrong and not your problem.~~

The link above is dead, but [this](https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/) might do the trick if a static database is OK.

Comment: link is dead :(

Comment: It's been 10 years, is I don't remember what that pointed to, but it looks like the better options are pay to play.

Comment: time passes but the need for free data doesn't

Answer (score 3):

Here is one for the USA https://web.archive.org/web/20101126192032/http://pablotron.org/files/zipcodes-csv-10-Aug-2004.zip

It's a CSV file that maps zipcodes to a latitude/longitude coordinate and a city name. The data is under a [CC BY 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/) license but it hasn't been updated since 2004.

Assuming your MySQL frontend is phpMyAdmin, see how to [import CSV](http://123techtalk.blogspot.com/2008/08/import-csv-to-sql-using-phpmyadmin.html) file, after that, delete columns you don't need, or do it before importing in lets say Excel.